# Bitmex Api for authorization

Tags: python

This is what i have try:

```
import time
import json
import hashlib
import hmac
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pprint import pprint

def generate_signature(secret, verb, url, expires, data):
    """Generate a request signature compatible with BitMEX."""
    # Parse the url so we can remove the base and extract just the path.
    parsedURL = urlparse(url)
    path = parsedURL.path
    if parsedURL.query:
        path = path + '?' + parsedURL.query

    if isinstance(data, (bytes, bytearray)):
        data = data.decode('utf8')

    print("Computing HMAC: %s" % verb + path + str(expires) + data)
    message = verb + path + str(expires) + data

    signature = hmac.new(bytes(secret, 'utf8'), bytes(message, 'utf8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    return signature


# Or you might generate it like so:
# expires = int(round(time.time()) + 5)

data = {
    'filter': {"symbol": "XBTUSD"},
   'columns': [],
    'count': 100
    'start': 1,
    'reverse': "true",
    'startTime': str(datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=50)),
    'endTime': str(datetime.now()) 

}

verb = 'GET'
path = '/api/v1/position'
time_in_epoch = int(datetime.timestamp(datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=.5)))

print("========",time_in_epoch, int(round(time.time()) + 1800))

expires =  time_in_epoch

gen_signat = generate_signature('api-sceret', verb, path, expires, json.dumps(data))

URL_get_data = "http://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/position" 
headers = {
    'api-expires': str(expires),
    'api-key': "api-key",
    'api-signature': str(gen_signat),
    }

response = requests.get(URL_get_data, headers=headers, data= data).json()
```

Still showing error:

> {'error': {'message': 'Signature not valid.', 'name': 'HTTPError'}}

If I pass this `gen_signat = generate_signature('api-sceret', verb, path, expires, data)` the showing `reponse<200>` but returns empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're basing on [this](https://www.bitmex.com/app/apiKeysUsage#Sample-Code) Bitmex sample. Please note that data must be JSON without whitespace between keys. The default separators value for `json.dumps` is `(', ', ': ')`, so you need to change your code to use `(',', ':')`. It should be `gen_signat = generate_signature('api-sceret', verb, path, expires, json.dumps(data,separators=(',', ':')))`.

Comment: I tried this gen_signat = generate_signature('api-secret', verb, path, expires, json.dumps(data,separators=(',', ':')))  but still showing same error.